# Responsive table: on mobile view go from three columns to two columns

Tags: html, sass, responsive

I have a table, which in desktop and tablet view, have three columns. The design given by designers shows that in mobile view, the third column should be gone and instead displayed in the same cell as the first column (see ref photo)
[image: Desired Design]

```
html: 
<table class="todoTable">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header-row">
                    <th class="question-header">Todos</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="details-row">
                    <td>
                        Todo 1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <div class="incomplete">
                         <span>Incomplete</span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript://">See details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="details-row">
                    <td>
                        Todo 2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <div class="incomplete">
                         <span>Incomplete</span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript://">See details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

```
scss
.todoTable {
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 20px;
   border-spacing: 0 14px;
   .header-row { 
     th {
       font-weight: 500;
       text-align: left;
       width: 50%;
     }
   }
   .details-row {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 600;
     td {
       border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
       border-style: solid none;
       line-height: 40px;
     }
     td:first-child {
       border-left-style: solid;
       border-top-left-radius: 4px; 
       border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
       padding-left: 21px;
     }
     td:last-child {
       border-right-style: solid;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; 
       border-top-right-radius: 4px; 
     }
   }
   .incomplete {
     color: red;
   }
   a {
     text-decoration: underline;
     color: #317cb7;
   }
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/someoneanonymous/8mh16bez/10/

Is it possible to have it like that using table elements or should I consider building the table with divs? My only concern is that I'm not sure whether doing it with divs aligns with accessibility reqs. Sorry, I know I should've approached it mobile first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a new table for mobile view only. Giving it a display: none; by default and only make it visible while on a mobile device. :-)